# How to display a user's OU using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a script that will display users specific properties, Name, Mail Address, OU respectively. the output is as intended however I can't find any solution to extract and display only the user's OU detail. when I select "DistinguishedName" the response is the following pattern: {CN = X, OU = Y, DC = Z}, I want to display only the OU. iv'e tried to find a method to split the DN String however no joy so far.

Thanks in advance

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
$filepath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ADusers.Csv"
$searchDomain = "DC = GSDOM, DC=internal"
$adminCredential = Get-Credential
$adSrv = 'GSDC'
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$adSrv" -Credential ($adminCredential)
Invoke-Command $session -Scriptblock { Import-Module ActiveDirectory }
Import-PSSession -Session $session -module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object "Name", "EmailAddress", "distinguishedName"
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An efficient way is to derive the OU from `DistinguishedName`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Mail |
    Select Name,Mail,DistinguishedName,@{n='OU';e={$_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?,(?=[A-Z]{2}=)'}}
```

This makes use of calculated properties, which can be found at [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7).

`-replace` uses case-insensitive regex for matching. Since we did not include a replacement string, the matched text is just removed. `-creplace` is the case-sensitive version. See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/2xeWAs/1) for the regex breakdown.

It is not wise to use `-Properties *` because that is potentially a large amount of data to return from a remote server. Since you are using `-Filter *` also, that means you would be returning all the attributes for all users. It is very slow and resource constraining.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, it was very helpful. so instead of using the -Filter * for selecting all the AD users, from my knowledge if I'll use the -Identity it will only return one user instead of all the users. 

Is there another way to retrieve all the AD users without using the -Filter *?

Thanks again for the help

Comment: `-Filter *` is fine. The `-Properties *` is what is not fine. The only way to use `-Identity` or a granular `-Filter` is to already have known data. Like if you know you only want to retrieve enabled users, you can do `-Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'`. If you have a list of `SamAccountName` values, you can loop through those and run specific `Get-ADUser` commands against them. But if that list is 1000s of objects, you may be better off returning all objects anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

i do it like this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Mail |
    Select Name,Mail,DistinguishedName,@{n='OU';e={($_.DistinguishedName.Split(",") | Where-Object {-Not $_.StartsWith("CN=")}) -join ","}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Default_Title = "OU=Users,OU=Workers,DC=ad,DC=colorland,DC=pl" 

$justName = $Default_Title.Split(',').Split('=')[-7]

$justName
```

It displays just Workers.

Answer (score 0):

The OU can also be found in the CanonicalName attribute. This looks more like a Directory structure as below.

DomainName/OU1/OU2/lastname, firstname

But as it uses "/" as a separator is some what simpler to use split on if users may have a "," in their DistinguishedName.

Adding the following in should get the desired result of the last OU before the username

```
e@{n=OU:e={($_.CanonicalName -split "/")[-2]}}
```

So a query like the following

```
Get-Aduser -filter * -properties CanonicalName | FT Name,@{n='OU';e={($_.CanonicalName  -split "/")[-2]}}
```

would return
Lastname, Firstname     OU2